# Slot(onUpdateCompleted) of Network config manager is taking ~5 min to get execute on overnight running system when we click first time on Qt C++ app

Tags: c++, qt

I have run the below code on MAC/Windows system. It works fine on windows.
On MAC I have observed the

1. Normal scenario onUpdateCompleted() is getting called on every second.
2. When we run Qt C++ application on overnight onUpdateCompleted() is also callen on every second.
3. Now if **we click on an application anywhere SLOT (onUpdateCompleted()) is taking time of ~5 min.** And the application is showing a wait cursor for 5 min. After 5 min it's used to work normally.

```
BearerMonitor::BearerMonitor(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
    QNetworkConfigurationManager   ConfManager;
    connect(&ConfManager, SIGNAL(configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)),
            this, SLOT(onConfigurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)));
    connect(&ConfManager, SIGNAL(updateCompleted()), this, SLOT(onUpdateCompleted()));
}
```

Comment: Is this the real code?  The `QNetworkConfigurationManager` instance is scoped locally within the `BearerMonitor` constructor and will be destroyed a s soon as the constructor completes.

Comment: No It's not real code. I kept it locally here because of data type reference.

Comment: Don't use SIGNAL and SLOT macros in new code. Also, we cannot help you debug this without a [mre]. Suggest you attach a debugger and break into the application when it is "showing a wait cursor for 5 min". That should help you see what is going on.

Comment: I don't know how to debug will help here. Here operating system plays some role when we click on the application. Otherwise, before clicking onUpdateCompleted() is called at every second. And I'm Using Qt 5.15.5 version in this application.

Comment: If you think OS is causing the delay in `updateCompleted`, why are you looking at your application?

Comment: Yes,  I'm also suspecting It. But I'm wondering about why it is happening for first-time clicks only.